# Get dependencies between classes in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am successfully getting dependencies between projects with Roslyn, and now I would like to get dependencies between classes, similar to the Code Map feature in Visual Studio Enterprise.

Here is my code, the "?????" part is where I imagine I could get something. I am very new to the Roslyn API, though, and I don't know how to proceed from there on.

```
        Solution solution = MSBuildWorkspace.Create()
            .OpenSolutionAsync(Path.Combine(repoRootFolder, "MySolution.sln"))
            .Result;

        ProjectDependencyGraph projdeps = solution.GetProjectDependencyGraph();

        Digraph graph = new Digraph();

        foreach (ProjectId projectId in projdeps.GetTopologicallySortedProjects())
        {
            string projName = solution.GetProject(projectId).Name;
            var projDeps = projdeps.GetProjectsThatThisProjectDirectlyDependsOn(projectId);
            foreach (ProjectId depId in projDeps)
            {
                Project dep = solution.GetProject(depId);

                Compilation compilation = dep.GetCompilationAsync().Result;

                foreach (var syntree in compilation.SyntaxTrees)
                {
                    foreach (var classNode in syntree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>())
                    {
                        var classesThisClassNodeReferences = ?????????
                    }
                }

                string depName = dep.Name;

                graph.Dependencies.Add(new Dependency
                {
                    Source = projName,
                    Target = depName
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean getting all used types withing that `ClassDeclarationSyntax`? You could get all `SyntaxNode`s, get the corresponding `ISymbol` through the semantic model, check if the symbol is an `INamedTypeSymbol` or not. But I think this will be extremely slow.

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam I need to generate dependency graphs and output them to PDF, so if it is slow it is not a deal breaker. But I could still not figure out how to perform the operation you propose. Could you perhaps post some code as an answer? It would help me a lot and I would test in my actual scenario as soon as possible.

Comment: @heltonbiker What library are you using for your Digraph?

Comment: @farlee2121 I created my own class, it's actually very crude, [here's the gist](https://gist.github.com/heltonbiker/6b38e4ed3c80d1b57e730a119c81aea8)

Comment: @heltonbiker Thanks! I also found several available on Nuget. The most popular seems to be [graphX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GraphX/)

Comment: @heltonbiker You may also be interested in this open source alternative to CodeMap that I found https://github.com/zebmason/DeepEnds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure about your requirements, but you can probably go for checking all descendant `SyntaxNode`s of the class and get the corresponding symbol, and it's type, and then collect these types. Something like the following:

```
var semantic = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntree);
var typesForCurrentClass = classNode.DescendantNodes().Select(n => 
  semantic.GetTypeInfo(n).Type);
```

Note that there can be multiple `typesForCurrentClass` for a given class symbol because of partial classes.

Comment: It worked, but it is giving me _every_ type the classes uses, even .Net types, ints, strings, etc. CodeMap (the VS Enterprise feature I am trying to replicate) usually puts this kind of thing inside "Externals" group, but I have no current interest in those dependencies. Would you know a way to make `typesForCurrentClass` contain only types defined in the solution? Thanks for the interest!

Comment: I'm not sure, you can check `type.ContainingAssembly`, and see if there's anything useful there.