# How do I determine which files my C# test depends on?

Tags: c#, automated-tests, impact-analysis

Consider I have a C# test project. Each test executes some code and that code could exist in other files that could be local to the project or could exist in another project in the same solution, or even in a project in another solution. How might I find out which files are "used" by my test?

It would be preferable that the solution requires no changes to the tests. It would also be preferable that the approach can be automated.

For example, say I have:

`Test.cs`

```
[Test]
public void Test() {
    var a = new Foo();
    a.bar();
}
```

`Foo.cs`

```
public class Foo {
    public void bar() { ... }
}
```

I would like to know that test `Test()` depends on `Foo.cs`.

Comment: By writing tests that test for a **single** thing, usually a single method within a single class. Anyway the test does not know **anything** about your soruce-code. So unless you don´t give your tests meaningful names, you´re stuck on the tests being self-explanatory.

Comment: It's not practical to have unit tests that are only dependent on a single method in a single class.

Comment: Maybe let Visual Studio create a code map on your unit tests?

Comment: "It's not practical to have unit tests that are only dependent on a single method in a single class" but that´s what unit-tests are about. Anything else woulb be an integration-test, where you check an entire component together with its dependencies.

Comment: I have updated my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Bleep-Bloop Thanks, that's a nice lead. I will check to see if it can be automated.

Comment: @DavidPoxon if you want to spend time, I am pretty sure that you can check out the dependcies with roslyn-framework. [Get dependencies between classes in Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235100/get-dependencies-between-classes-in-roslyn)

Comment: I repeat myself: the test doesn´t know **anything** about your source-code, it only knows the compiled code. Imagine your class `Foo` was `partial` and consists of two different sourcecode-files, `Foo1.cs` and `Foo2.cs`. For the test those files don´t exist, only the (compiled) class `Foo`.

Comment: I'm happy to do a static analysis, but was wondering if there might be an existing solution or simpler approach that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @HimBromBeere but why are you making that point? I haven't mentioned anything about compiled code or a run-time analysis.